# UML-actors in the use case

Tags: web, uml, diagram, use-case

Let's say that i have started making an use case diagram for tourist agency web application. So what bothering me is the thing that i am not sure should i make administrator role and connect him with other actors with the generalization because they share common behaviors.

For example, i have web-site visitor as a role, then i have registered one who can book hotels... Now i was thinking of putting the administrator role who would have permissions to do what ever he wants to do. So all i need is your advice and what you would do if you will ever have the similar problem.

Comment: I don't think this question belongs on SO, but, yes, the actors would be the users (clients) and the app's administrators. And if the travel agencies, hotels and whatnot have access, their users would be actors as well. The question is just too broad to give you any useful answer.

Comment: @Gabriel Yeah i have this role as well but i didn't want to mention because its not the topic of my question. One more thing, i have read somewhere that administrator should be included only if he posses some unique possibilities. Like deleting users from the system

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do that. And it's a common pattern. An actor represents (plays) a role within the system under consideration. And if you find people acting with different roles you can apply a generalization. Especially if you generalize `Administrator` from `User` this says that the admin can do anything the user can do.

Comment: Exactly what you have said "admin can do anything the user can do". Thanks man, you helped me once and here we go again.